# Is it possible install to iOS app without itunes

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have made the build and I have to send someone.. If he does't have PC or Mac, only he has just iphone. then how can he install build over his iphone. (If it is possible.)

Thanks

Comment: I wonder how that someone managed to activate his phone in the first place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mandeepd you can use beta builder
check the steps
[Using Beta Builder](http://amit-battan.blogspot.com/2011/10/ios-beta-builder-send-ios-app-build-as.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the free service of [TestFlightApp](http://www.testflightapp.com/).

Comment: +1 because I love Testflight and would have suggested using it, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hudson](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Meet+Hudson) or [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) to compile your App with every check-in (you are using scm, right?), and [hockey](https://github.com/TheRealKerni/Hockey#readme) for browser-based deployment.
See this [blogpost](http://nachbaur.com/blog/building-ios-apps-for-over-the-air-adhoc-distribution) for more informations.

<sup>Note: we are using this setup in my company. But I can't give you the codes, as they are the intellectual property of my company.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use the procedure from the URL Below to distribute app over the air http://iosdevelopertips.com/xcode/distribute-ad-hoc-applications-over-the-air-ota.html

Answer (score 0):

If his iPhone is jailbroken he can SSH it to /Applications but it would show up as a native/jailbroken app (no delete button in wiggle mode) and with no icon bevel

Answer (score 0):

the excellent way to do this is [Beta Builder](http://media.ratevegas.com/BetaBuilder.app.zip)

Comment: if you don't have a server you can use DropBox